# Can I use the postman cli to generate the corresponding curl?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am running a postman cli based query involving a complex authentication process without actually building a website.

I've got everything worked out and am successfully running a final authenticated postman request for a secure token and refresh token using the postman cli.

However, although the postman cli appears to receive the complete response on my local computer, it only reports the first 2 or so kilobytes of response.  And, it reports that response in an awkward manner that I'll have to parse.

Accepting that I can't get postman to just give me the response straight up, is there a way to get the cli to generate the curl command?